# Http with Azure AD - Graph API - POST Method - Powerapps

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, powerapps, outlook-restapi

I'm not able to send a POST or PATCH action thru the connector because I can't figure out how to compose the body correctly.

I try it that way:
[image: Invoke http with Azure AD]

But I get this error:
[image: Error]

I try it without brakets, with more brakets, with single, double and without quotations but it seems nothing works.

Please can anyone tell me how to compose the body in the right way?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Look like the body is not a valid json. Properties `givenName`, `surname`, etc. should be wrapped by quotes.

```
{
  "givenName": "Microsoft",
  "surname": "Graph",
  "emailAddresses": [
    {
      "address": "Microsoft.graph@api.com",
      "name": "Microsoft Graph"
    }
  ],
  "businessPhones": [
    "+334100100"
  ],
  "mobilePhone": "+9857665765"
}
```

Comment: That's how I tried the first time with the same result.